# How to update the SemanticModel in Roslyn after changing the SyntaxTree?

Tags: c#, .net, abstract-syntax-tree, roslyn

I am trying to perform a syntax transformation in Roslyn. The AST rearrangement works fine, but, as I am changing stuff, I will need to get an updated `SemanticModel` that reflects the new structure of my `SyntaxTree`.

### Transforming the tree

**This part works**, and I can tell because I have done extensive debugging.

```
CSharpSyntaxTree tree = RetrieveTree(); // Just successfully gets the original tree
CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(...); // Retrieves the compilation object

CompilationUnitSyntax node = tree.GetRoot();

// Doing stuff to change the tree
node = node.RemoveNodes(...);
node = node.AddMembers(...);
```

So I can get the new tree:

```
CSharpSyntaxTree newTree = node.SyntaxTree as CSharpSyntaxTree;
```

I can see, by debugging, that `newTree` has the new structure, while `tree` has the old. Also I can successfully traverse `newTree` and operate on the AST. So the transformation was successful.

### Updating tree and semantics

I think the **problems start here** when I try to update the `CSharpCompilation` and when I get the `SemanticModel` out of it.

```
CSharpCompilation newCompilation = compilation.ReplaceSyntaxTree(tree, newTree);
SemanticModel newSemanticModel = newCompilation.GetSemanticModel(newTree);
```

Because when I try:

```
TypeSyntax myClassTypeNode = GetSourceCodeClassTypeNode(); // Just successfully gets a node
var symbol = newSemanticModel.getSymbolInfo(myClassTypeNode).Symbol;
```

Then `symbol` is null. Of course it keeps being `null` also if I try to use the original `SemanticModel`.

**Without transformation it works** If I do not perform the transformation and use the old `SemanticModel`, the symbol is successfully retrieved!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try newSemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(myClassTypeName)

Comment: @DudiKeleti: Always `null`. The point is that I do not think the problem is `getSymbolInfo` as that was working without transformation. The problem is that I am not doing things in the right way for updating the `SemanticModel`.

Comment: It seems that you do the replacement. Ill take a look soon.

Comment: One more thing, did you check for compilation errors? compilation.GetDiagnostics()

Comment: @DudiKeleti: Oh shit... Of course... I am rearranging everything so there are problems when referencing stuff. I am actually moving classes into new namespaces so... That is the problem!

Comment: a new compilation (with the new syntax trees, w/o the old one) is needed, to get the new semantic model

Comment: Look at the DocumentEditor Class

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer but I hope it will be useful for someone. In my experience if it's impossible to fetch symbols from the semantic model after replacing nodes with [`SyntaxNode.ReplaceNode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.syntaxnodeextensions.replacenode), and updating the compilation with [`CompilationReplaceSyntaxTree`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.compilation.replacesyntaxtree), it's because an error was introduced when replacing nodes. It's easy to introduce subtle mistakes when plugging nodes created with the [`SyntaxFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.syntaxfactory?view=roslyn-dotnet-4.6.0) API, nodes that just look correct (but in fact they are not) because some similar nodes emit the same exact code, and the replacement functions will be very lenient just to discover errors later in the semantic analysis. One trick I discovered is to test the compilation for errors with the following extension method:

```
public static List<string> GetCompilationErrors(this Compilation compilation)
{
    var diagnostics = compilation.GetDiagnostics()
        .Where(d => d.Severity == DiagnosticSeverity.Error)
        .Select(d => $"{d.Location}, {d.Id}: {d.GetMessage()}")
        .ToList();
    return diagnostics;
}
```

Provided the tree manipulation is semantically correct, if no error are detected with the above function then the semantic model should produce the expected results.